# Trying to add string to float variable in tkinter label/entry widgets

Tags: tkinter, osx-lion, python-3.4

I'm hoping to get some guidance on an issue I've been spending far too much time trying to solve. Every time I find a solution another problem takes its place.

My aim is to 'simply' do some basic maths on some figures and then add a '$' at the start of the float variable.

At first I tried this:

```
self.paid_main.set("$", self.paid_entry.get())
```

Error:

```
TypeError: set() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I'm obviously missing something here as I thought I gave 2 arguments - "$" and self.paid_entry.get()

Then I tried:

```
paid = ("$", self.paid_entry.get())
self.paid_main.set(paid)
```

This works but gives a horrible looking result on the GUI. Instead of just placing a dollar sign there, it puts curly braces around it. e.g. {$}

However beggars can't be choosers so I stick with the horrible curly braces option, until a little bit further down I run into this issue.

```
total_main = ("$", "%.2f" % self.quantity_entry.get() *   self.paid_entry.get() + self.brokerage_entry.get())
self.total_main.set(total_main)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Again, I must be missing something since when can't you multiply a float?

I can solve all my issues if I choose not to add a dollar sign in front of anything, but then I'll be settling for second best. I'm hoping someone can help me with the following questions:

1. What are the 3 positional arguments, as I can only count 2?
2. Is there a way to provision for another argument?
3. Is there a way to add a dollar sign without curly braces?
4. Why am I getting the error trying to multiply a float?

I should note, I have to set the IntVar and DoubleVar variables to an empty string as leaving it will add 0 and 0.0 respectively to the label coordinates before I even click on 'add.' Unless there's another way of avoiding this?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

Full code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4

from tkinter import *
import ystockquote
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import decimal

class Shares(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    Frame(self ,width = 500, height = 300)
    self.configure()
    self.grid()

    Label(self, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "      Name    ").grid(row = 8, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(self, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "      Code    ").grid(row = 8, column = 3, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(self, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "    Buy Date  ").grid(row = 8, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(self, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "    Quantity  ").grid(row = 8, column = 5, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(self, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "      Paid    ").grid(row = 8, column = 6, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(self, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "    Brokerage ").grid(row = 8, column = 7, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(self, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "      Total   ").grid(row = 8, column = 8, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(self, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "     Current  ").grid(row = 8, column = 9, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(self, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "      Total   ").grid(row = 8, column = 10,padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(self, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "  % Loss/Gain ").grid(row = 8, column = 11, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    Button(self, text = "New Record", command = self.dialogue_box).grid(row = 9, column = 0)

def dialogue_box(self):
    top = self.top = Toplevel()

    Label(top, text = "Code: ").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(top, text = "Buy Date: ").grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(top, text = "Quantity: ").grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(top, text = "Paid: ").grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(top, text = "Brokerage: ").grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    self.code_main = StringVar()
    Label(self, textvariable = self.code_main).grid(row = 9, column = 3, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    self.code_entry = StringVar()
    Entry(top, textvariable = self.code_entry).grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.code_entry.set("")

    self.date_main = StringVar()
    Label(self, textvariable = self.date_main).grid(row = 9, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.date_main.set("")

    self.date_entry = StringVar()
    Entry(top, textvariable = self.date_entry).grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.date_entry.set("")

    self.quantity_main = IntVar()
    Label(self, textvariable = self.quantity_main).grid(row = 9, column = 5, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.quantity_main.set("")

    self.quantity_entry = IntVar()
    Entry(top, textvariable = self.quantity_entry).grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.quantity_entry.set("")

    self.paid_main = DoubleVar()
    Label(self, textvariable = self.paid_main).grid(row = 9, column = 6, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.paid_main.set("")

    self.paid_entry = DoubleVar()
    Entry(top, textvariable = self.paid_entry).grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.paid_entry.set("")

    self.brokerage_main = DoubleVar()
    Label(self, textvariable = self.brokerage_main).grid(row = 9, column = 7, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.brokerage_main.set("")

    self.brokerage_entry = DoubleVar()
    Entry(top, textvariable = self.brokerage_entry).grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.brokerage_entry.set(29.95)

    self.total_main = DoubleVar()
    Label(self, textvariable = self.total_main).grid(row = 9, column = 8, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.total_main.set("")

    self.current_main = DoubleVar()
    Label(self, textvariable = self.current_main).grid(row = 9, column = 9, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.current_main.set("")

    self.total_two_main = DoubleVar()
    Label(self, textvariable = self.total_two_main).grid(row = 9, column = 10, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.total_two_main.set("")

    self.loss_gain_main = DoubleVar()
    Label(self, textvariable = self.loss_gain_main).grid(row = 9, column = 11, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.loss_gain_main.set("")

    Button(top, text = "Add", command = self.add).grid(row = 5, column = 0)

def add(self):
    self.code_main.set(self.code_entry.get())
    self.date_main.set(self.date_entry.get())
    self.quantity_main.set(self.quantity_entry.get())
    paid = ("$", "%.2f" % self.paid_entry.get())
    self.paid_main.set(paid)
    brokerage = ("$", self.brokerage_entry.get())
    self.brokerage_main.set(brokerage)
    total_main = ("$", "%.2f" % self.quantity_entry.get() * self.paid_entry.get() + self.brokerage_entry.get())
    self.total_main.set(total_main)
    self.current_main.set(ystockquote.get_price(self.code_entry.get() + ".AX"))
    total_two = (self.current_main.get() * self.quantity_entry.get())
    self.total_two_main.set(total_two)
    rounded = ((self.total_two_main.get() / self.total_main.get() * 100) - 100)
    self.loss_gain_main.set("%.2f" % rounded)
    self.top.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    master = Tk()
    master.title("Shares program")
    app = Shares(master)
    master.geometry("1280x550+0+0")
    master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to concatenate text using `+` and `str()` if element is not text.

```
self.paid_main.set( "$" + str(self.paid_entry.get()) )
```

`self.paid_main` is treated as first argument for `set()`.

---

```
paid = ("$", self.paid_entry.get())
```

This creates tuple `("$", some_value)` - it doesn't concatenate elements.

`,` creates tuple or separates arguments in function like `print(args1, args2, ...)`

---

It can be one problem: `self.paid_main` is `DoubleVar()` and you can't set text to it. You have to use `StringVar()` to set text with `$`

---

In this

```
total_main = ("$", "%.2f" % self.quantity_entry.get() *   self.paid_entry.get() + self.brokerage_entry.get())
```

use bracket to calculate value before you use it with `%`

```
total_main = "$%.2f" % (self.quantity_entry.get()*self.paid_entry.get() + self.brokerage_entry.get())
```

or

```
value = self.quantity_entry.get()*self.paid_entry.get() + self.brokerage_entry.get()
total_main = "$%.2f" % value
```

without brackets Python treads this as

```
text = "$%.2f" % self.quantity_entry.get()
total_main = text * self.paid_entry.get() + self.brokerage_entry.get()
```

Comment: Hi furas, thanks for your post. I'm still getting some very strange errors though. If I add `("$", self.paid_entry.get()))` and `("$" + str(self.brokerage_entry.get()))` then `self.total_main.set("$" + str(self.quantity_entry.get() * self.paid_entry.get() + self.brokerage_entry.get()))` works fine, but the last line `rounded = ((self.total_two_main.get() / self.total_main.get() * 100) - 100)
        self.loss_gain_main.set("%.2f" % rounded + "%")` throws an error. `ValueError: could not convert string to float:` Why would this cause an error and the previous line not?

Comment: Essentially what I'm asking is, why does this work `("$" + str(self.quantity_entry.get() * self.paid_entry.get() + self.brokerage_entry.get()))` and this fail `rounded = ((self.total_two_main.get() / self.total_main.get() * 100) - 100)` ??

Comment: Problem is `self.loss_gain_main` - it is `DoubleVar()` so you can't set text with "$" and "%" because it is not correct float number. Try `float("$123%")` and you get error.

Comment: This is why I'm confused. `self.total_main` is also `DoubleVar()` yet we can add "$" to it.

Comment: I checked this. `DoubleVar()` accept any text but problem is when you use `get()` - it tries to convert text to returns float and then it gets error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my own question. It turns out this code:

```
self.total_main.set("$" + str(self.quantity_entry.get() * self.paid_entry.get()))
```

Would then convert `self.total_main` to a string, even if it was initialised as `DoubleVar()`

I had to go the long way around by creating multiple variables of the same value and feed it through when needed. eg. `self.current_main.set()` would become a string when adding `$` therefore I needed to set `current_main` as another variable with the same value, which would be a float and then the calculation `curent_main * self.quantity_entry.get()` would work.

```
self.current_main.set("$" + str(ystockquote.get_price(self.code_entry.get() + ".AX")))
curent_main = float(ystockquote.get_price(self.code_entry.get() + ".AX"))
total_two = curent_main * self.quantity_entry.get()
self.total_two_main.set("$%.2f" % total_two)
```